# Classification Neural network cost stop changing after 1 iteration?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, classification, python

I tried building a classification neural network using python without any deep learning library.
the code runs without error but the cost decreases only at the first iteration and nothing much on the rest of the iterations.

The resulting prediction also only predicts the same class for all test samples. Below are the functions that I made.

```
def forward_prop(x, w, b):
z = {}
a = {}
a[0] = np.array(x).T
last = len(w)
for i in range(1,(last+1)):
    z[i] = w[i-1].dot(a[i-1]) + b[i-1]
    if i == last:
        a[i] = softmax(z[i])
    else:
        a[i] = sig(z[i])
pred = a[last]
return pred, a    

def back_prop(y, p, a, w, b):
    d = {}
    d_w = {}
    d_b = {}
    last = len(w)
    d[last] = (p-y.T)
    for i in range(last-1, -1, -1):
        if i == last-1:
            d[i] = w[i].T.dot(d[i+1])      # 10 x 1 --> d2
        elif i != 0:           # No need to get d0
            d[i] = w[i].T.dot(d[i+1]) * sig_deriv(a[i])
        d_w[i] = d[i+1].dot(a[i].T)        # dw2 
        d_b[i] = np.sum(d[i+1], axis=1, keepdims=True)
    return d_w, d_b

def update(w, b, d_w, d_b, a):
    for i in range (0,len(w)):
        w[i] = w[i] - a * d_w[i]
        b[i] = b[i] - a * d_b[i]
    return w, b

def sum_error(y, p):
    z = np.sum(y.T * np.log(p))
    return here
```

Activation Function

```
def sig(x):
    return 1.0/(1.0 + np.exp(-x))     

def sig_deriv(x):
    return x*(1.0-x)                      

def softmax(x):
    #z = np.exp(x-x.max())
    z = np.exp(x)
    s = z.sum()
    out = z / s
    return out
```

Here are the training loop

```
def train(x, y, w, b, epoch, learn_rate, batch):
    c = []                                 
    t_v = np.argmax(y, axis=1)           # True Value ( 1 / 0 )
    err_rate = np.zeros(epoch)           # Error rate for each epoch
    for i in range(0, epoch):
        e = 0                            # Reset
        p = np.zeros(len(x))             # Prediction ( 1 / 0 )
        for k in range(0, len(x)):       # Loop through training datasets
            pred, layer = forward_prop(x[k:k+batch], w, b)
            w_grad, b_grad = back_prop(y[k:k+batch], pred, layer, w, b)
            w, b = update(w, b, w_grad, b_grad, learn_rate)
            e = e + sum_error(y[k:k+batch], pred)
            p[k] = np.argmax(pred, axis=0)  # Prediction ( 1 / 0 )
        cost = -e/len(x)
        c.append(cost)
        err_rate[i] = cal_acc(t_v, p)
        if (i%(epoch/20)) == 0:
            print('iteration:',i,' cost:' ,cost)
    return c, err_rate, w, b
```

And this is the cost plotted

[image: Plotted cost]

Edit(1)
Here are the constants I used

```
features = range(1,35)
batch_size = 1
epochs = 400
learn_rate = 0.0001
hl = 2                          # Numbers of hidden layers
nodes = [20, 20]                # Node of each hidden layer
output_node = 2                # Output node
```

Edit(2)
Old initial W and B

```
def init_model(x, hl, node, p, batch):
    w = {}
    b = {}
    if len(node) < hl:
        node = np.tile(node,hl)
    n = np.hstack((x,node,p)).ravel()                     # Number of layer, including in and out
    for i in range(0,(len(n)-1)):
        w[i] = np.random.rand(n[i+1],n[i])          # row = output ; column = input
        b[i] = np.random.rand(n[i+1],batch)         # Row = nodes ; column = batch = 1
    return w, b
```

New one

```
def init_model(x, hl, node, p, batch):
    w = {}
    b = {}
    if len(node) < hl:
        node = np.tile(node,hl)
    n = np.hstack((x,node,p)).ravel()                     # Number of layer, including in and out
    for i in range(0,(len(n)-1)):
        w[i] = np.random.rand(n[i+1],n[i]) - 0.5          # row = output ; column = input
        b[i] = np.random.rand(n[i+1],batch) - 0.5         # Row = nodes ; column = batch = 1
    return w, b
```

Comment: Have you tried using smaller learning rate?

Comment: I tried up to 0.00001 as learning rate. The cost went down but still converge to a point not far below the starting one. It still predicts one class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the mistake and it was found in the code that I didn't post.
It was my initial weight and bias. I initiate it using `np.random.rand` and the range is between 0 - 1.
It seems that the changes in my delta weight and bias is very small (also the learning rate is small) resulting in not much change in weight and bias per update

I now initialized my weight between -0.5 to 0.5 and the result is fine